# Scientific term for “Characteristic time”

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

What term is commonly used in scientific vocabulary for "characteristic time", i.e. for typical time of some process?

We suppose process is not periodical, and "period" does not fit that well.

Usage example:
"characteristic time" of continental drift
Which may refer to time around 150 million years which is enough to completely change visual view of continents.

Comment: What's wrong with "typical time" (or perhaps "typical elapsed time")?

Comment: Is it TAT (Turn-around time)? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2282400/

Comment: @RamPillai - "Turn-around time" is how long it takes to move the locomotive to the opposite end of the train.

Comment: If you don't like 'time' you could use 'typical duration' in many cases.

Comment: They both seem to be slightly better than "characteristic time", but at the same time in Russian "characteristic time" have very distinctive meaning. If you search in google you will find much more specific answers on non-common words.

Comment: In light of the edit and example, adaptation, differentiation, and speciation don't have characteristic times. The mechanisms are various and complex, and the driving forces are myriad and random. Characteristic time is only meaningful in much less complex systems with well-behaved drivers.

Comment: Last time I checked in recent million years that was rather distinctive. Dinosaur era, for example.
But I changed example again to try to be more specific. Answer of Global was actually very close and I remember seeing "time scale" in similar context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Characteristic time* is often used in models where there is exponential decay.  It is the time taken for the decaying quantity to fall by a factor of 1/*e*.

More generally, there is *scale time*, which refers generically to the units you might use to describe the changes taking place.

The wikipedia has some examples: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_scale

Comment: This is very nice answer, and so far closest to what I hoped. Can't vote yet, but will mark it as accepted if there will be no alternatives.